# Makefile fails to see main.o one out of two times

Tags: c++, macos, build, makefile, clang++

Ok, I'm trying to build a makefile in order to compile a program on different environments. On Linux (Mint) it works just fine, but under Mac OS I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

With the '-v':

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -w -o bin/Darwin/main ./cfprintf.o ./file.o ./inputmanager.o ./neditfile.o ./neditmanager.o ./neditscreen.o ./n_string.o ./sys_booter.o ./sys_display.o ./sys_manager.o ./sys_screen.o -lc++ -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Now here's the makefile:

```
CC = clang++
LIB = 
INC = -I src/
OPTIONS = -w

OBJS = $(shell find ./src/obj -name '*.cpp')
IO = $(shell find ./src/io -name '*.cpp')
SYS = $(shell find ./src/sys -name '*.cpp')
APPS = $(shell find ./src/apps -name '*.cpp')

EXEC = bin/$(shell uname)/main

.PHONY: dummy build all objects io sys apps incBC clear run

build: clear incBC objects io sys apps
    @echo "-> Compiling main... "
    @$(CC) -c src/main.cpp $(INC) $(OPTIONS)
    @echo "-> Building environment... "
    @$(CC) $(shell find . -name '*.o') $(LIB) $(OPTIONS) -o $(EXEC) -v
    @echo "-> Removing all objects file from compilation... "
    @rm *.o

objects:
    @echo "-> Building objects files and classes... "
    @$(CC) -c $(OBJS) $(INC) $(OPTIONS)

io:
    @echo "-> Building input/output files and classes..."
    @$(CC) -c $(IO) $(INC) $(OPTIONS)

sys:
    @echo "-> Building system files and classes..."
    @$(CC) -c $(SYS) $(INC) $(OPTIONS)

apps:
    @echo "-> Building all apps files and classes..."
    @$(CC) -c $(APPS) $(INC) $(OPTIONS)

incBC:
    @echo "-> Updated build count..."
    @./incBC.sh

clear:
    clear

run:
    cd bin/$(shell uname)/ && clear && ./main
```

Now what's (al least to me) really weird, is that when I type `make` it fails one out of two times... LITERALLY one out of two! And when it does fail, I get the error message above. What I've noticed from that message is that, in the `ld` command, there is no `main.o` which is probably why I get the undefined reference. My question is: why? Why specifically one out of two times, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bizarre makefile.  Why not just write a shell script?  There's nothing in this makefile that takes any advantage of make itself: it will always rebuild everything every time.  The point of writing a makefile, instead of a shell script, is so you can *avoid* rebuilding objects that haven't changes.

Anyway, the reason you're seeing failures is that you're using make's `$(shell ...)` function *inside* of a recipe.  This is not necessary, because a recipe is already running in a shell.  The reason this fails for you is that make will expand the entire recipe (all lines) *first*, before it starts your recipe (it has to do this obviously).  That means that because you're using `$(shell ...)` that `find` command is run before the recipe runs, and before the recipe runs you haven't compiled your `main.o`, so the `find` command doesn't include it in the list of object files found.  Then the next time you run it, `main.o` exists from the previous run so the `find` command finds it.

Change this line:

```
@$(CC) $(shell find . -name '*.o') $(LIB) $(OPTIONS) -o $(EXEC) -v
```

to this:

```
@$(CC) `find . -name '*.o'` $(LIB) $(OPTIONS) -o $(EXEC) -v
```

and it will work.

Although it's still not very useful as a makefile.

Comment: Thanks!! From what I read, I suppose my recipes (rules I guess) should be of the form: '***.o:' to be more effective eh? I guess it's my next step then! Thanks again